# Set NTP flag linux time from c++

Tags: c++, linux, time, ntp

Is there a way to turn off NTP synchronization in a linux system
from a c++ program, to obtain the same result you get with:

```bash
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

I have no idea where to start from, also std::chrono documentation does not give info about this argument.

I would like to obtain to stop programmatically the ntp synch, so that I can set the date/time from the same c++ application

Comment: `std::system("timedatectl set-ntp ...")`

Comment: Not every system uses timedatectl to manage NTP. I don't have it installed. Do you want it to work on all systems (impossible) or just yours and ones like it?